# GIT : All new branches come under previous branch

Tags: android, git, github, branch

i'm new to git
SO this is my repo
https://github.com/nayak94/nayak-kernel
was working on the branch 0.1 
now wanted to try some new feature so made a branch 0.2
using "git checkout -b 0.2"
now it shows that https://github.com/nayak94/nayak-kernel/branches 0.2 is merged with 0.1 
can someone explain how this works , read through many tutorials couldn't get it 
how can i create a new branch without merging with an old one ?

Comment: I have made an update, please take a look at

Comment: thanks for walking me through , kudos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new branch, git forks the new branch from the current branch you are on, in your case, it is `0.1`.

If you want to create branch from `master`, you should switch to master and create branch from there.

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git checkout -b 0.2`

After that you have two branches (`0.1` and `0.2`) created from `master` branch.

**As a side note:** `git checkout -b branch_name` creates a branch and switches to that branch. Meanwhile `git branch branch_name` creates a branch but stays on the current branch. If you have used the second option, you shouldn't have had this problem.

Comment: well , what if i want to continue progress from 0.1 but as a new branch below master?

Comment: If you want the changes that are done in 0.1, you should `git merge 0.1` when you are on `0.2` branch